# Why does jQuery "toggle" button trigger the Submit button on a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a fairly complex form which includes a hidden section that the user can toggle open for entering more information if necessary. However, when you click on this toggle button labeled **I have more Nativities**, it triggers the submit button and prematurely submits the form.

The form is in dev right now, but it can be found [here](http://www.dayofservice.org/christmas/registration).

The code I am using for the toggle button is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#schedule").accordion({ header: "h5", collapsible: true });
        $("#more-nativities").hide();
        $("#toggle").click(function()   {
            $("#more-nativities").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The code for the submit button is pretty basic:

```
<input id="submit2" type="image" src="_images/btn_register.jpg" name="submit"  alt="" onmouseover="javascript:this.src='_images/btn_register2.jpg'" onmouseout="javascript:this.src='_images/btn_register.jpg'"/>
```

The code for the toggle button is:

```
<button id="toggle">I have more nativities</button>
```

Any ideas as to why the toggle button is triggering the submit? And more importantly how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest not using [inline JS. Write unobtrusive Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064166/is-there-any-good-reason-for-javascript-to-be-inline).

Comment: It's very helpful to provide as much pertinent code as possible. I edited in your original code for the toggle button.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding a type, i.e.:

```
<button type="button" id="#toggle">Text</button>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp says this should be always defined. It's possible the browser is defaulting to a submit button.

Comment: I don't know what you see but the button has no type.

Comment: Not seeing it on my browser. All I have is:
<button id="toggle">I have more nativities</button>

Comment: @SimpleCoder - I didn't realize that was the code being referred to... I thought this was about the `<input>` button. The code for the `<button>` tags wasn't included in the OP. I've edited it into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Esteban has one solution. A better one is described in the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(event){
     alert("As you can see, the link no longer took you to jquery.com");
     event.preventDefault();
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 return false;
```

after the slide toggle on the click function fro the toggle button.

Answer (score 1):

From W3Schools:

> Always specify the type attribute for
>   the button. The default type for
>   Internet Explorer is "button", while
>   in other browsers (and in the W3C
>   specification) it is "submit".

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Be sure to specify `type="button"`