# jquery submit function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a webpage which creates a form with various select tags dynamically. Unfortenatley the jquery submit function passes incorrect information to the php file (form_submit.php) that must process this information; the (netbeans 7.4) debugger always shows default (not selected) values in $_POST within the php file instead of the selected values . The even stranger part: when I copy (in the code below) the console output with the serialised formdata  straight into the following ajaxcode (see code), the php debugger shows the correct -selected values within the $_POST array..(?)

The resulting form is quite substantial. The only theoretical cause I can think of is that therefore the execution of 'var dataAjax = $( this ).serialize();' takes time and is not finished when the following ajax call starts...(??)

The code:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();

var dataAjax = $( this ).serialize(); //does not work, but when copying the string from the console in line below it does work.
console.log('SUBMITTED FORM: '+ dataAjax  );
//next line is only used as a test
//var dataAjax = 'agreementapproval0=SolarX_10&selected_emeterproductid0=SolarX_10_1_1&selected_eproductid0=SolarX_10_2_4&selected_emeterproductid1=NOSELECTION&selected_emeterproductid2=NOSELECTION&selected_eproductid1=NOSELECTION&selected_eproductid2=NOSELECTION&form_token=30688e467ee88167805ad0f330809d74';


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "form_submit.php",
        data: dataAjax, 
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,

        success: function(msg){
        if(msg.statusgeneral == 'success'){

        }
        else
        {

        }//else
        }, //succes: function   
        error: function(){

    $("#errorbox").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
        }
    });//.ajax

//make sure the form doesn't post
//return false; //depreciated

//} //if(form.valid()

});//$("#myForm").submit()


<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post">    
    <div id="wrapper"></div> <!--anchor point for adding set of product form fields -->  
    <input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="<?php echo $form_token; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Comment: First, move `event.preventDefault();` to the first line of the event handler. this prevents the form from submitting even if an error occurs. Next, check the console for errors (after making the change)

Comment: You might have an issue where the `.serialize` method returns a URL-encoded string, meaning that space would be `%20`, and so on. Maybe your php code, or something in between, does not like this. [reference](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: @Kevin B: thnx, just did that, but no change and no errors in the console. The console does give a warning 'event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.'

Comment: @Cort3z PHP automatically decodes form data, it's *required* that it be URL-encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine http://jsfiddle.net/a9DN4/

You might have been trying to hook form before it have been created, try to wrap your code with

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

PS and move `event.preventDefault();` to the 1st string of your function, as Kevin says.

Comment: thnx. sorry, I didnt include the document-ready code on this page, but it is included in my original code. Also added Kevin B's suggestion but without effect.

Comment: ps: perhaps a thick question: how do I see with your jsfiddle that's working? I start getting the impression the problem relates somehow to the Netbeans debugger...(?)

Comment: @user2543182 it sends content of the hidden field, you can check it with firebug or chrome console: http://i.imgur.com/LzCZWW2.png. I assume that your php is correct, so there will be actual token instead.

Comment: @all: thnx for all your help(!) I just found the cause of the problem: My webpage includes some buttons to show and hide content (using jquery toggle(). Obviously every time I pressed that button the submit function is activated (didnt know that) as I just noticed with the console, and therefore the php file is called with still unselected values. Only took me 10hrs today to discover...

Comment: @user2543182 Don't worry, I had pretty same situation: 8 hours of watching exactly on the cause of my troubles and not a single guess about what's wrong with this code))

Comment: makes me feel much better. ps: just noticed the solution for the button issue as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747749/why-does-jquery-toggle-button-trigger-the-submit-button-on-a-form